# How to read all files from a folder randomly

Tags: php, cookies

Hy friends I used this code when I save my cookie in database to get 49random cookies

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"
SELECT
*
FROM
token_all Order By Rand() Limit 49
");
if($result){
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
$m = $row['token'];
}
}
```

But now I am saving cookie in a file with different user I'd name and now I am trying  to get 49 random cookies from the folder were all files are saved.... How I do this?
 ***Here is the screenshot***

[Files screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tD2M.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem what i saw is you are over-writing your variable `$m` inside `while()` loop, and hense you will get only last record.

To overcome this, do like below:-

```
$m = []; //define as array
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $m[] = $row['token']; //assign each value to array
}
```

***To get all files you can use like below:-***

```
if ($handle = opendir('add directory path here')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {

            echo "$entry\n";
        }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to fetch MySQL read the ques carefully.... I am asking that how to fetch file from folder because I don't want to use MySQL